# Mikhlin multiplier theorem at origin?

Tags: fourier-analysis, lp-spaces, harmonic-analysis

The Mikhlin multiplier theorem states the following:

Theorem [Theorem 2, Davide Guidetti
Vector valued Fourier multipliers and
applications]. Let $m$ be a bounded function on $\displaystyle \mathbb{R}^{n}$ which is smooth except possibly at the origin, and such that the function ${\displaystyle |x|^{k}|\nabla ^{k}m|}$ is bounded for all integers ${\displaystyle 0\leq k\leq n/2+1}$: then $m$ is an $L^p$ multiplier for all $1 < p < \infty$.

Why not considered at the origin? At origin is trivial? (Because if $x=0$ then ${\displaystyle |x|^{k}|\nabla ^{k}m|}$ is bounded automatically?

Comment: well if $x=0$ then what is the meaning of $\nabla^k m(x)$, since $m$ is not necessarily assumed to be smooth at $0$? PS a prototype operator I believe should be something like $x/|x|$ for $x\in\mathbb R^n$

Comment: Ok but if $m\in C^{n}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (i.e. now includes 0
)  the theorem is holds?

Comment: Yes, if the theorem holds without assuming it, you can of course add more assumptions, and the theorem will hold. The proof won't use it. E.g. you can also assume that $|m|<5$.